# user pay for premium content using sms

Tags: paypal, sms

My site which have premium content should grant access to privileged users. These users should be assigned into privileged group only when they send sms to some number. How can I collect money from these user sms on my paypal account.

I have premium content and paypal account. Already spend too much time looking for decent explanation of this approach, but I didnt find any useful tutorial.

So, please share some links or thoughts which explains what steps I should complete in order to set this like explained above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMS transactions are suitable if you offer services or content at a very low price, bellow dolar and up to 10$, otherwise it makes no sense. You should consider to remove user membership based on this payment, mainly for reason that this method of payment is used for anonymous users.

Google is your friend, some better investigation and right keywords and you should find answers.

Hope this helps, good luck.